# Php curl post exactly like the browser

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I want to do a login with Php curl, I imagine tha I post to the site like the browser, but I can't loggin.

this is how I post the site

```
$curl = curl_init();
$optArray = array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.example.com/login.php',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_VERBOSE=> true,
  CURLOPT_NOBODY=> true,
  CURLOPT_HEADER=> true,
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT=> 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/125.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/125.8',
  CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'path of the cookie file with write permissions ',
  CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'path of the cookie file with write permissions',
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
  CURLOPT_REFERER => 'the referer'
  CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'username=xxx&password=xxx'
);

curl_setopt_array($curl , $optArray);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

the $result variable contain the HTML of http://www.example.com/login.php width no change.

please can someone tell me how to post exactly like the browser.

what curl option that I am missing.

I'm verry sorry for my english.

Comment: Please add to your question what happens when you try this.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think that cURL is very difficult to handle.
IMO it's much easier to use a library like guzzlehttp/guzzle (I let you Google for it) that wraps cURL in object oriented way. It will let you create requests with that kind of code :

```
$httpClient = new GuzzleHttp\Client;
$login = $httpClient->post('http://www.example.com/login.php', $optionsArray);
```

DISCLAIMER : It's just an example, it's obviously not exactly the code you will need. Don't use my code and read the official documentation instead.

By the way, many login forms use a [CSRF protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) that doesn't allow you to login that way.

Comment: thanks pimolo for your response, I will try the GuzzleHttp librairie.